# Batch Updating a column in the DevExpress GridView

Tags: devexpress

I have read everything there is to read online about this topic and none of the proposed solutions work.

My situation is very simple...

I have a grid that loads data....

Once the grid is loaded, the user can edit a specific column and change the value of the field (see below code snippet): Note that after the grid is databound, I check the VisibleRowCount property and get 1057 rows.

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Charge" FieldName="Charge" Width="100px" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" PropertiesTextEdit-DisplayFormatString="{0:c2}" VisibleIndex="4">
 <DataItemTemplate>
 <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxCharge" runat="server" Width="75px" Text='<%# Eval("Charge") %>'>
 </dx:ASPxTextBox>
 </DataItemTemplate>
 </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

At this point, a button is clicked on the form to execute a code-behind method that I want to do the following with:
I simply need a way to do loop through all the rows on the grid one by one and update the modified value in my database. 
Note that I can take care of whether or not the value has been modified. 
All I need is access to the row and the specific column to get the modified value.

I tried using the VisibleRowCount property in my code behind method, but this value evaluates to 0.  Obviously, after a postback, the VisibleRowCount property is set back to 0 so I can't loop through the grid collection. I tried saving the value in ViewState, but the VisibleRowCount property is obviously readonly.

```
int visibleRowCount = Utility.GetValue<int>(ViewState["VisibleRowCount"]);
                    for (int i = 0; i < visibleRowCount; i++)
                    {
                        DataRow aspxDataRow = updateItemsGridView.GetDataRow(i);

                        Array arr = aspxDataRow.ItemArray;
```

How can I accomplish this apparent simple issue???

​

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're doing it that way but you could try putting them in a list.

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < updateItemsGridView.VisibleRowCount; i++)
{
     ids.Add(Convert.ToInt32(updateItemsGridView.GetRowValues(i, "Charge")));
}
```

Comment: It still won't matter, because the VisibleRowCount is set back to 0 on a postback. There must be some kind of property on the grid I can access to cycle through the collection of rows after a postback.

Comment: strange, because I am using the same code above in production at my workplace, it works fine even after a postback.